# Using dijikstra with some updation

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search, dijkstra

In the Dijkstra algorithm, we know that first, we declare all the nodes at an infinite distance from 1.Then we looking in the adjacency list of the current node, whether the distance of its child from itself is minimum or not. If maximum, then we update the distance array of that child. But Now We can perform an operation that we can divide any weighted edge by a particular number (k) i.e INTEGER DIVISION. We can perform this operation ONLY ONCE. Now we have to find the minimum distance to reach from 1 to N.

CONSTRAINTS:

1 ≤ N ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>

1 ≤ M ≤ 2⋅10<sup>5</sup>

x,y ⇒ [1,N]

1 ≤ K ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>

Suppose the graph is as follows:
N=4, M=4 and K=3;

1 2 70

2 4 190

1 3 10

3 4 438

a,b,c where a and b are connected, and c is its distance.
For this case , the answer is 133.
making 190/3 and then add with 70 to reach 4.

So, what are the changes we have to make in the standard Dijkstra algorithm to get the desired result.?

Comment: @Henk yes , it is .see the sample case for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just one value that corresponds to the shortest path for each vertex, you can store a pair of values. One for the shortest path where one edge has been divided by k and one for the shortest path.
To update pairs when considering an edge, the shortest value with a divided edge is the minimum of two cases.

So in the beginning of your example you would store (\infty, \infty) for the vertices 2,3  and 4. Then you consider the edges incident to 1 and modify them:

- 2: (70/3, 70)
- 3: (10/3, 10)
- 4: (\infty, \infty)

Then you go on with 3 because 10/3 is the smallest value:

- 2: (70/3, 70)
- 3: (10/3), visited
- 4: (min(10/3+438, 10+438/3, 10+438) = (156, 448)

Now, we consider vertex 2 because it has the smallest unvisited value:

- 2: (70/3), visited
- 3 (10/3, visited
- 4 (min(156, 70/3+190, 70+190/3), min(448, 70+190))=(133, 260)

Now 4 is visited, which is the endpoint, so 133 is the shortest path with that possibility.

Comment: can u please explain taking my sample case. I am not getting

Comment: sir, just tell which two values you are talking about to store for each node?

Comment: Sir, but answer is 133. U are getting 156.

Comment: Please add this part in ur answer

Comment: Sir, it is my request to please implement ur above answer by creating a function  in c++ language for better understanding

Comment: are u there sir?

Comment: Anyone here who can implement Henry's approach in c++ code?

Comment: Please reply anyone